# "Date 'Nov 15, 1950' is not recognized" Error in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

view in snowflake as follows;

I am trying this below query

`select "Date of Birth"::date, * from table_name;`

but it is giving me below error

`Date 'Nov 15, 1950' is not recognized.`

May I know how can I handle this date error issue?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That date is not recognized by default, you will need to specify a format for it.

So this works:

```
select to_date('Nov 15, 1950', 'MON DD, YYYY');
```

I get back:

```
1950-11-15
```

For more information on date formats, have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#about-the-format-specifiers-in-this-section).